# Failover physical and virtual machine with replication. Is it possible?

Tags: ubuntu, cluster, replication

I want to create HA cluster with 2 nodes. First node is physical machine, second is virtual (under ProxMox). Both running under Ubuntu. I know how to make HA with corosync and pacemaker. How i can make replication/mirroring of partitions? Is it possible without using NAS storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly possible using SAN technology instead of NAS.  *Question answered ! Applause!*

---

As the above is very probably not what you wanted to hear as SAN is more expensive than NAS, you *can* also do that using [DRBD](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/drbd.conf-9.0.5.html) *however* it's going to be a highly customized system that no one else except you is going to be able to maintain.  The logical solution is SAN or if you can't afford SAN, use NAS.

Comment: That it is what i expected to hear, thank you

Comment: Favour returned.  Question upvoted!  **:-)**